# Raspberry Pi Firmware version

Tags: raspbian, firmware

How can I determine which version of the Raspberry Pi firmware is installed on my Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 4):

You can check the kernel version like this:

```
uname -a
 Linux RPi 3.1.19 #1 PREEMPT Fri Jun 1 14:16:38 CEST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

And the GPU firmware with:

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
May 31 2012 13:35:03
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 317494 (release)
```